# C++ code not compile - match argument list

Tags: c++, compilation

I have this code using lodepng library for loading PNG files. Library is OK, succesfully used in other projects, wihout problem.

```
const std::string tmpString = mapFileName.GetConstString();
    std::vector<unsigned char> xx;
    unsigned int error = lodepng::decode(xx, (unsigned int)this->mapWidth, (unsigned int)this->mapHeight, tmpString, LCT_GREY, (unsigned int)8);
```

I want to compile this, but getting weird error message.

```
MapHelper.cpp(72): error C2665: 'lodepng::decode' : none of the 5 overloads could convert all the argument types
          c:\ImageUtils\lodepng.h(200): could be 'unsigned int lodepng::decode(std::vector<_Ty> &,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,const unsigned char *,size_t,LodePNGColorType,unsigned int)'
         with
          [
              _Ty=uint8
          ]
          c:\ImageUtils\lodepng.h(203): or       'unsigned int lodepng::decode(std::vector<_Ty> &,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,const std::vector<_Ty> &,LodePNGColorType,unsigned int)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=uint8
          ]
          c:\ImageUtils\lodepng.h(211): or       'unsigned int lodepng::decode(std::vector<_Ty> &,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,const std::string &,LodePNGColorType,unsigned int)'
          with         
 [
             _Ty=uint8
          ]
          c:\ImageUtils\lodepng.h(759): or       'unsigned int lodepng::decode(std::vector<_Ty> &,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,lodepng::State &,const unsigned char *,size_t)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=uint8
          ]
          while trying to match the argument list '(std::vector<_Ty>, unsigned int, unsigned int, const std::string, LodePNGColorType, unsigned int)'
          with
          [
              _Ty=uint8
          ]
```

I cant see whats wrong, types of input parametrs are same as in library and there can be no collision in types.

**EDIT**
Function, where I have `lodepng::decode` is not const

Comment: Are you sure all of those `unsigned int` casts are necessary?

Comment: @chris They are useless, but without them, behaviour is the same. I wrote them just to match function parametrs exactly to the ones of lodepng

Comment: I am using same code in different project and everything is compiling just fine. I know, that compiler can not match function, but I dont see why. My used types are the same as in 3rd decode function in list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I would have expected a more precise error message, but given the presence of an overload with this signature

```
'(std::vector<_Ty> &,unsigned int &,unsigned int &,const std::string &, LodePNGColorType, unsigned int)'
```

compared to your own invocation

```
'(std::vector<_Ty>, unsigned int, unsigned int, const std::string, LodePNGColorType, unsigned int)'
```

then the problem must lie in the fact that the former wants `unsigned int&` while you supply `unsigned int`.  While this is normally fine it isn't in this case because you cast to `unsigned int` in the function call, creating an R-value.  So try this:

```
unsigned int wd = (unsigned int)this->mapWidth,
             ht = (unsigned int)this->mapHeight;
unsigned int error = lodepng::decode(xx, wd, ht, tmpString, LCT_GREY, (unsigned int)8);
```

Passing by reference is generally used to give outputs back to the calling code.  If `wd`, `ht` serve only as outputs, then actually you don't need to initialize them and

```
unsigned int wd, ht;
```

is good enough.  Either way `wd`, `ht` will have new values after the function returns and you will probably need to finish up with

```
this->mapWidth = wd;
this->mapHeight = ht;
```

Comment: Thanks, solved.. didnt realize, that I cant do conversion to reference.